# Got an "email verification" email. Is it really from here?

Tags: support, email

It said the following. It is really from StackExchange? I have been on this site for some time and don't think I have ever seen such a message.

> Please verify your Electrical Engineering Email address
>
> To make sure that you receive emails, we need to confirm your email
>   address. All it takes is a single click.

Here are the first few headers. Since 10.x.y.z isn't a public IP address, I can't be sure about anything from that. The SPF warning is concerning.

```
Received: by 10.204.141.81 with SMTP id l17cs33255bku;
        Wed, 14 Sep 2011 10:32:39 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.204.156.16 with SMTP id u16mr77874bkw.54.1316021558381;
        Wed, 14 Sep 2011 10:32:38 -0700 (PDT)
DomainKey-Status: good
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: best guess record for domain of transitioning do-not-reply@stackexchange.com does not designate 64.34.119.36 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.34.119.36;
Received: by 10.205.80.68 with POP3 id zt4mf813920bkb.21;
        Wed, 14 Sep 2011 10:32:37 -0700 (PDT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are sending out a one time verification email when you sign up to receive new answers on a questions that you ask.  This is to confirm that there is a real human at the other end of these emails we send.

Comment: You might consider making them one site-wide. After posting this question I also got one from meta.

Comment: Upon further evaluation we have reconsidered the verification emails - they will no longer go out after the next build upon asking a question and asking for daily answeres on your question.

Answer (score -5):

Look at the headers and see where it came from immediately before it got to your machine or server, then check who owns that IP address.  Also look at the message carefully and see where that click (hopefully you didn't actually click it, right?) would really go.  If it's not some place in the stackexchange.com domain then it's fraudulent.

Now why didn't you do these basic, simple, and obvious things before asking?

Comment: Yes, I did check the links. And since they were to http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/email/confirm?... I did suspect they were valid. I figured that asking since I didn't see this question previously asked would help others with this question in the future. However there is no need to be insulting. I don't think checking who who owns an IP address is obvious (nor is how to check).